# Making geometry blink in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

Is it possible in QGIS to make a geometry blink?

With blinking I mean making a geometry or group of geometries appear and disappear every N milliseconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the **TimeManager** plugin which allows you to animate features based on a time attribute. Particularly, there is an animation option which allows you to display frames for a specified number of milliseconds:

[image: TimeManager plugin]

You can find more information from the [blog](http://planet.qgis.org/planet/tag/time%20manager/) which contains tutorials on how to use the plugin and add various effects.

Comment: And would it be possible, at the same time, to make it disappear for a specified number of milliseconds? Using Time Manager we can control its display, but not for how long it will be hidden.