# Hiding layer for N seconds in QGIS: animate symbols with custom intervals

Tags: qgis, symbology, expression, time, animation

This is a follow-up to [Making geometry blink in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162544), for which I couldn't find any answer online.

It is relatively simple, using the Time Manager plugin or the Temporal Controller native tool in QGIS, to animate (display) a layer for a certain amount of seconds.

*But how would we control it if we want that layer to be hidden for another N amount of seconds?*

Let's say we have two layers that represent two lighthouses, and we want to recreate the pattern of its blinking lights:

Assuming they both start at the same time, but one is on for 4 seconds and off for 1 second, and the other is on for 5 seconds and off for 5 seconds, how would we animate this and make the animation loop forever?

Is there any expression that would be useful in the Geometry Generator?

Comment: Take a look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310223/blinking-symbology-in-qgis-on-database-values or the lately introduced "Animated Marker" symbol style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @MrXsquared, there is a [new `Animated Marker` since QGIS 3.26](https://qgis.org/lt/site/forusers/visualchangelog326/index.html#feature-allow-any-symbol-to-be-an-animated-symbol). This works even without Time Manager plugin or the native Temporal Controller. See [this follow up question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/469303/88814) for what more complex use cases you can use it.

Proceed as follows (screenshots and animation for demonstration below):

1. In the Layer Styling, select the top level of the symbol Marker, go to <kbd>Advanced</kbd> > <kbd>Animation Settings...</kbd> and set a Frame rate of 1 fps (frames per second). Make sure the `Is Anmimated` box is checked.
2. Back in the the Layer Styling, select the Simple Marker entry and go down to <kbd>Enable symbol layer</kbd> and click data defined override (icon <kbd>`ɛ`</kbd>).
3. To make the symbol be on/off for 5 seconds each, add the expression `@symbol_frame % 10 < 5`. Proceed the same way for the other layer, to be on for 4 and off for 1 second, use `@symbol_frame % 5 > 0`.

Or, even better, if both symbols are on the same layer, to animate the point with id=1 for 5/5 seconds, the other one for 4/1 seconds, use this expression:

```
case 
when id = 1
then @symbol_frame % 10 < 5
else @symbol_frame % 5 > 0
end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: In case we'd need to use on/off periods shorter than 1 second, would this still be valid or should we change the fps accordingly? For example, if we have a light whose period goes on and off for 0.5 and 2 seconds.

Comment: I would change fps. See also here how to deal with milliseconds: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/469355/88814

Comment: `@symbol_frame % 2` results in 0/1 (true/false or visible/not visible = blinking) and fps set to 2 results in 2 frames per second, one visible for 0.5s, one not visible for 0.5s = blinking (one look in 1 s). For 2 seconds, set frame rate to 0.5 etc.

Comment: For a project in which the patter is 0.5 s on, 2 s off, 0.5 s on again and then 6 s off for a total of 9 seconds, I had an hybrid approach between this and your other method: I multiplied the values by 2 in order to get whole numbers and using this expression with a framerate of 8 fps, it works good. The only problem is the already mentioned issue with the refresh rate affecting other layers. However, I cannot adapt it to a framerate of 1 fps, as the animation renders too slow. 
@symbol_frame/4 % 18 > 0 AND @symbol_frame/4 % 18 <= 1 OR @symbol_frame/4 % 18 > 5 AND @symbol_frame/4 % 18 <= 6